# Unable to find type [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]

Tags: linq, powershell

I installed the module using
`Install-Module -Name newtonsoft.json`
Even then it shows the error. I even tried `Add-Type -AssemblyName Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` Nothing worked. Help please!

```
PS C:\Users\m-00261-2>   `$rawJson = [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]::Parse($rawString)`
Unable to find type [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject].
At line:1 char:14
+   $rawJson = [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]::Parse($rawString)
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound


PS C:\Users\m-00261-2> `Add-Type -AssemblyName Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`
Add-Type : Cannot add type. The assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' could not be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -AssemblyName Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject:String) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

Comment: Maybe the file has a different path.

Comment: Use `Add-Type -Path 'path\to\newtonsoft.json.dll'`

Comment: Or y'know.. load the module so the assembly is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a statement `Import-Module newtonsoft.json`.
This fixed the similar issue for me.